# cardinality of a maximal subgroup of a $p$ group

Tags: group-theory, maximal-subgroup

Let $P$ be a $p$ group with $|P|=p^n$. Let $M$ be a maximal subgroup of $P$. Is it true that $|M|=p^{n-1 }$ ?

Comment: Yes. Now you should try to prove this (there are several ways, most of which at some point use that the center is non-trivial).

Comment: Center of a $p$-group is non trivial ?

Comment: Yes, this is one of the most basic properties of $p$-groups (it follows from the class equation), and tends to be the starting-point for most proofs of properties that holds for all $p$-groups.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate way is to observe that any maximal subgroup $M$ of a $p$ group is normal. So $G/M$ is a simple $p$ group. But every $p$ group has non trivial centre which implies $G/M$ is abelian and hence has to be isomorphic to $Z/pZ$. This proves the claim.

Answer (score 0):

We proceed by induction

Center of a $p$-group is non-trivial, hence there exists an element of order $p$ in the center of a $p$-group, call this element a.

Hence the quotient $G/<a>$ is a $p$-group of order $p$^$(n-1)$ hence all it's maximal subgroups are of the order $p$^$(n-2)$ (by the induction hypothesis)

Now if the original group G has a maximal subgroup H of order $p$^$a$ where $a<p-1$ then the subgroup $H/<a>$ of $G/<a>$ is also maximal in $G/<a>$ (apply correspondence theorem) and order of $H/<a>$ is less than $p$^$(n-2)$ (a contradiction)